# Using delay DispatchQueue in "for in loop"

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, for-in-loop

The task is to change the background color once a second. Was used "for in loop". For delay, a DispatchQueue was used. Everything seems to be fine, but it was noticed that after 10 iterations, the background color begins to change with a delay of 2 seconds, a little later in 3 seconds. The more iterations, the greater the delay. I displayed time in the console (seconds) to see how it changes. I see the results, but I do not understand what is wrong. I did the task through a timer, there were no problems, but I want to understand what is wrong with the DispatchQueue delay.

```
for i in 1...150 {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i)) {

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                                          green: .random(in: 0...1), 
                                           blue: .random(in: 0...1), 
                                          alpha: 1)
         print("\(ymd)")

         ymd = self.myCalendar.dateComponents([.second], from: Date())
    }
}
```

Console:

```
second: 21 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 21 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 22 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 23 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 24 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 25 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 26 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 27 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 28 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 29 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 30 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 32 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 33 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 33 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 35 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 35 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 37 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 37 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 39 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 39 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 41 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 41 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 44 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 44 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 44 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 47 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 47 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 47 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 50 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 50 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 50 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 54 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 54 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 54 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 57 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 57 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 57 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 57 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 1 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 1 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 1 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 1 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 6 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 6 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 6 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 6 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 6 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 11 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 11 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 11 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 11 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 11 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 17 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 17 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 17 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 17 isLeapMonth: false 
second: 17 isLeapMonth: false
```

Comment: This is just a really bad way of trying to time something.  When you call the async, your timing is all messed up. It will happen the next time it can get to the queue.  And you are queueing up 150 async queue requests.  It's a pretty non-standard way to do it.  You should use a repeating timer with an index

Comment: As @HalR already said, you should use a Timer for this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30095236/8162321) is a good example, how you can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of “timer coalescing”, in which the “leeway” for the dispatched block is 10% of the delay, up to a max of one minute of leeway. (This is [buried in the libdispatch code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/4659503fee11a3c0cad79a771de53dbde0ca92cc/src/source.c#L1340).) It’s a power saving feature to coalesce/group distant, independently scheduled tasks to run at the same time to avoid unnecessary spinning up the hardware too many times. The easiest way to avoid this coalescing is to use a repeating timer:

```
var counter = 0

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    counter += 1

    guard let self = self, counter <= 150 else {
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                                      green: .random(in: 0...1),
                                       blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                                      alpha: 1)

    let ymd = self.myCalendar.dateComponents([.second], from: Date())
    print(ymd)
}
```

Note the use of the `[weak self]` pattern, to avoid having the timer keep a persistent reference to the view controller. And with that `guard` statement, we’ll `invalidate` the timer if the view controller is dismissed.

BTW, if you want to make the color change less jarring, animate the change:

```
var counter = 0

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    counter += 1
    guard let self = self, counter <= 150 else {
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                                          green: .random(in: 0...1),
                                           blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                                          alpha: 1)
    }

    ...
}
```